# How to filter a datetime field in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

So I am trying to filter a field then delete all of those inside that field, but it just doesn't work. I am using flask-sqlalchemy not sqlalchemy.
The code:

```
            bans = Ban.query.filter(Ban.banend >= datetime.now()).all()
            print(bans)
            for ban in bans:
                db.session.delete(ban)
            
            db.session.commit()
            print("Deleted all bans that needed to be deleted")
```

The model:

```
class Ban(db.Model, JsonModel):
    ...
    banend = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)
    ...
```

There is no error but it doesn't get the items it needs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `banend` is a date which the ban ends. I believe the logic should be

```py
bans = Ban.query.filter(Ban.banend <= datetime.now()).all()
```

This will return all records where `banend` is BEFORE the current date (aka they should have expired).

If I am misunderstanding could you edit your question to include the items which are (incorrectly) returned?